# VBA modeless form stops Function Keys

Tags: vba, excel, modeless

I'd like to have my own help file in my Excel program.

In the

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
```

I have

```
Application.OnKey "{F1}", "Help"
```

That works when I'm on the Excel sheet but my application is based on a fullscreen main userform which is displayed modeless.

When the userform is visible it blocks the <kbd>F1</kbd> key somehow and the macro doesn't fire.

I thought that modeless forms didn't block code execution.

Any hints how can I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to trap the `keyDown` event on the UserForm itself. When the UserForm has got the focus, whatever Key you press it goes to the UserForm.

```
'/UserForm1 is a sample name.

Private Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
     If KeyCode = 112 Then '/ F1
        Call Help
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Didn't tought about that. Thanks 
Unfortunatelly this doesn,t work 
I tried to trap `Keydown` `KeyUp` and `KeyPress`. None of them is fired when I use keyboard with the form displayed fullscreen.
Looks like the form doesn't get focus. 
From the begening. There is a form displayed full screen. 
Couple of images on a form and a big frame with some controls on it.
That's all.